# Titanium: App not being deployed to iOS simulator after iOS 9 upgrade

Tags: ios, node.js, xcode, titanium

XCode decided to do an upgrade to iOS 9, and after that the app refuses to deploy to the emulator.
The build works ok, but it fails at this:

```
[INFO] :   Invoking xcodebuild
[INFO] :   Finished building the application in 40s 523ms
[INFO] :   Launching iOS Simulator
[ERROR] :  Project failed to build after 1m 21s 108ms
[ERROR] :  An error occurred running the iOS Simulator (ios-sim exit code 1)
TRACE  | titanium exited with exit code 1
ERROR  | Error: ti run exited with error code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/stop/.appcelerator/install/5.0.1/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/plugins/run.js:89:66)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:12)
```

Any ideas?
There's no updates that i can install, it says everything is up to date.

I have SDK 5.1.0. installed

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i did 2 things here, not sure which one fixed it.

1. I ran appc setup and let it finish
2. I removed all the errors around the icons and images that were missing and were the wrong size.

After that it just started working. Not sure which of the 2 fixed it.